# How do I stop feeding the wild animals?

Tags: towns

In the latest version of Towns (v9) a few changes seem to have been made in the way harvesting is handled.

I've tilled a nice 5x10 plot of land and assigned it to wheat farming, but so far only 14 squares of it have been planted -- and every time one of them pops wheat, a nearby townie harvests it and feeds it to a random wild animal rather than finish planting the field.

Because of this, I'm perennially short on wheat; is there any way to tell my townies to stop feeding the damn animals and plant the wheat instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, my mistake -- they weren't actually *wild* animals, they were *domesticated* animals spawning from my ranches. Slaughtering most of my livestock and closing down all but a few of my ranches allowed my townies to focus wheat harvests on planting the rest of the field.